# Google reCAPTCHA fail for second time submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-chrome, captcha

I implement the reCAPTCHA in this tutorial,

https://codeforgeek.com/2014/12/google-recaptcha-tutorial/

which work well for the first time submit. The problems I have are:

1. I send the captcha with other form data e.g. username , email etc.... so if captcha is correct but other not , the user will send it again, but the second time it return "{ "success": false }"
2. if I idle it for ~2 min , it will session expire and if I select the box it pop up alert and warning something like " can not refresh : invalid parameter", and I can not select the box again

How to fix those problem? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Google reCAPTCHA gives these two functions: I always use this in all my AJAX powered forms.

> `grecaptcha.getResponse()`
>
> `grecaptcha.reset();`

For both of your problems, use the second function whenever you need in your JavaScript code.

> Remember this works if you have only one CAPTCHA in your page. If you have more than two CAPTCHAs use their IDs as explained in Google Docs

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#js_api

Comment: Thank you.This fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Those who have the same problem and meet this topic during research;
If you experience problem when you render the captcha automatically, try to render it explicitly. In order to do this, add following code inside body tag.

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=recaptchaCallback&render=explicit&hl=tr" async defer></script>
```

2. ```
                           var recaptchaCallback = function () {
                              //  alert("grecaptcha is ready!");
                               grecaptcha.render("YOUR HTML DIV ID", {
                            'sitekey': 'YOUR SITE KEY', 
                               });
                           };
   ```
3. I'm using AJAX to check registration form and get response. So I have added reset function to my AJAX response.

   `$('#frmRegistration').submit(function () {
                                   $.ajax({
                                       url: "_ajax/_ajaxRegistration.php",
                                       type: "POST",
                                       data: $('#frmRegistration').serialize(),
                                       success: function (reply) {
                                           $('#resultRegistration').html(reply);
                                             grecaptcha.reset();
                                       }
                                   });
                               });`

Reference [Google reCaptcha explicit render](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#explicit_render).